# perl hash reference's reference

Tags: perl, reference

```
my $hash_ref = { a => 1, b => 2 };
my $tmp_ref = $hash_ref;
```

The code is as above and I want to change hash's value and insert some new pairs. my question are as follows:

1. how can i achieve these by `$tmp_ref`
2. Is it possible to change or insert by reference's reference?
3. Is it consistent among reference's reference, reference and concrete data structure (here is hash)?

thanks a lot!

Comment: You can get a reference of a reference, but I don't think you would ever need to. A direct reference is sufficient. But what might be useful is a nested data structure, e.g. a hashref whose hash values are references to inner hashrefs

Answer (score 3):

In this case, `$tmp_ref` is not a reference to `$hash_ref`, it is simply a copy of whatever `$hash_ref`'s value is.

You can access the hash with `$tmp_ref` like you would with `$hash_ref`:

```
$tmp_ref->{a}; # 1

$tmp_ref->{foobar} = "hi";
$tmp_ref->{foobar}; # "hi"
```

In case you actually wanted to make `$tmp_ref` a reference to `$hash_ref`, here is how you'd access the original hash:

```
$tmp_ref = \$hash_ref;
${$$tmp_ref}{a};
```

Answer (score 2):

Both `$hash_ref` and `$tmp_ref` will refer to the same hash so you can add something to `$hash_ref` with:

```
$tmp_ref->{c} = 3;
```

Then both `$hash_ref` and `$tmp_ref` will <s>point</s>refer to the same `(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3)` hash.

References are Perl's version of pointers.